# Preventing reset on serial monitor connect?

Tags: serial-port, arduino, arduino-ide

Is there a way of preventing the reset when starting the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 17):

For the Uno, connect a 10μF capacitor between the reset and ground pins.

For other Arduinos, a 120 Ohm resistor (or equivalent resistance made up of multiple resistors, since 120 Ohms is quite rare on its own) between the 5V and Reset pins should do the trick.

Comment: This means I can simply place a capacitor/resistor between the reset and ground pin on a running Arduino board and then connect without the common reset?

Comment: Correct. I have a couple of Unos running this way, no problems at all.

Answer (score 4):

The arduino Playground site has a quite detailed breakdown of different methods of preventing your arduino from restarting, with a bit of background and explanation.

http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection

Answer (score 2):

If you would connect a Windows PC, This rudimentary Powershell script works (tested on Arduino Mega):

```html
$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM8,9600,None,8,one
$port.DtrEnable = $false
$port.open()
while ($true) {
 $nChar = $port.BytesToRead
 if ($nChar -gt 0) {Write-Host -NoNewline $port.ReadExisting()}
}
```